# Microsoft C Compiler .EC and .C source files

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I've inherited some code written for the (ancient) Microsoft C compiler 2.x. For each .c file, there is a .ec file of the same name. If I modify the C file and compile the code, nothing is different, but modifications to the .ec file take effect. Upon compiling, the .c file is updated to match the changes to the .ec file.

I've scoured the Internet for information about this compiler and I can't find anything. Why is there an EC file? It doesn't seem right to modify the EC files; I must be doing something wrong. I was expecting the .c file to contain the source code.

If anyone here used this compiler "back in the day," I'd appreciate any insight/information you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The extension `.ec` is the old C with embedded SQL extension, and is probably unrelated to Microsoft C. Your build system probably generates the `.c` file from the `.ec` file using a preprocessor. Look for `exec sql` statements in the `.ec` file embedded inside otherwise normal looking C code. Is there a relational database hanging around?

Unlikely to have anything to do with gcc preprocessor extensions.

Comment: Also look for an `esql` command being invoked from your build scripts - that's what processes the .ec files and outputs the .c file for the compiler. (I don't think that cl.exe invokes `esql` itself, but I suppose it's possible).

Comment: An Informix database is indeed part of the application. The compiling is done through a batch script that contains an `esql` command. Everything makes perfect sense now. Just to be sure, I treat the `.ec` files as the main source files, correct? The way I understand it, I can delete the .c files and they will be re-generated when the esql command is run.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The `.ec` files are the main source files, and the `.c` files are generated by `esql`.

Answer (score -1):

A `.ec` is an expanded c file, basically the output of the preprocessor.  See http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_36.html.

Use `gcc` with the `-e` to produce this file.

Comment: holy crap @Richard, I still have C and MASM diskettes going back to v1.0 but no way to install anymore.  You are awesome in your back support.  Do you do Cobol as well?  Fortran '66?  '77?  Just kidding of course!